# .NET DataGrid and CRUD

Tags: .net, datagrid, crud

I often have to use DataGrid in Win / web forms in .NET (2.0 or 3.5).

Like typical business application, I have tables joined by primary/foreign keys in DB, and select data using Joins and manipulate this data in UI.

Even while displaying data, I find it difficult to customize columns in grid, say, I often have to add a ComboBox column, bind it to some dataset / list.

When it comes to add / update / delete, things get worse as we have to modify more than one table, after finding appropriate rows.

I often wonder is there any proven framework / guide available on achieving this day-to-day (and yet challenging) task of CRUD data thru' UI.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very exciting. The best available framework on .NET is MVVM and you can couple it with WPF or SilverLight to have the best UI experience.

You can read more about MVVM here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: 9 classes and few XAMLs just to show / add a (simple) customer record!!

Comment: Right, but that eases the maintenance in the long run and in case of growth of the app. Also with WPF, you can take it to Web or Winworks very easily. Are you looking for other ways?

Comment: Yup! I am looking more specific solutions w.r.t DataGrid and also which may not involve 3.5 technologies like WPF, etc.